# Group rows with a value depending on condition of a different column SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a list of rows that I need to group by a key and for each group the value of two columns depends on a condition from a different column.

For example
[image]

should become
[image]

That means, for the value of Col 5 take the one where col 4 is the lowest and for the col 7 take the value where col 6 is the highest.

Any idea how to achieve this result?

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information to answer here.  How do we know which value to take?

Comment: As explained. the value of Col 5 should be the the value on col 5 where col 4 is the lowest and for col 7 the value on col 7 where col 6 is the highest.  The image shows that  I take the PI01041635) because the lowest col 4 value is 20190601(the lowest in col 4) and for col 7 I pick PI0113027 because the col 6 is 20200303(the highest on col 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that your group is determined by your key column

```
;with r as (
    select Key, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7, Col8,
    row_number() over(partition by key order by Col4) as c4,
    row_number() over(partition by key order by Col6 desc) as C6
)
select distinct r1.Key, r1.Col1, r1.Col2, r1.Col3, 
    r2.col4, r2.col5, 
    r3.col6, r3.col7, 
    r1.col8
from r r1
join r r2 on r2.key=r1.key and r2.c4=1
join r r3 on r3.key=r1.key and r3.c6=1
```

Comment: You need a `distinct` so that it will return 1 row instead of 2, and you need a `from table` in the first `select` statement.  Very clever BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset is hard to work with because you do not have a unique key on each record.  Having a unique key would simplify the query a lot.  This does what you are asking:

```
create table #temp ([Key] char(1), [Col 1] varchar(8), [Col 2] varchar(8), [Col 3] int, [Col 4] varchar(10), [Col 5] varchar(10), [Col 6] varchar(10), [Col 7] varchar(10), [Col 8] varchar(10))

insert into #temp values
('A', 'XXX', 'AAA', 5, '20190601', 'PI0104163', '20190429', 'PI0104163', '20190531'),
('A', 'XXX', 'AAA', 5, '20200129', 'PI0113027', '20200303', 'PI0113027', '20190531')

select distinct 
       t1.[Key]
      ,t1.[Col 1]
      ,t1.[Col 2]
      ,t1.[Col 3]
      ,[Col 4] = case when t1.[Col 4] < t2.[Col 4] then t1.[Col 4] else t2.[Col 4] end
      ,[Col 5] = case when t1.[Col 4] < t2.[Col 4] then t1.[Col 5] else t2.[Col 5] end
      ,[Col 6] = case when t1.[Col 6] > t2.[Col 6] then t1.[Col 6] else t2.[Col 6] end
      ,[Col 7] = case when t1.[Col 6] > t2.[Col 6] then t1.[Col 7] else t2.[Col 7] end
      ,t1.[Col 8]
from   #temp t1
       inner join #temp t2 on
         (t1.[Key]   =  t2.[Key]  ) and
         (t1.[Col 1] =  t2.[Col 1]) and
         (t1.[Col 2] =  t2.[Col 2]) and
         (t1.[Col 3] =  t2.[Col 3]) and
         ( /* do not match a record to itself */
           (t1.[Col 4] <> t2.[Col 4]) or
           (t1.[Col 5] <> t2.[Col 5]) or
           (t1.[Col 6] <> t2.[Col 6]) or
           (t1.[Col 7] <> t2.[Col 7])
         ) and
         (t1.[Col 8] = t2.[Col 8])

drop table #temp
```

Which returns this data:

```
Key  Col 1    Col 2    Col 3       Col 4      Col 5      Col 6      Col 7      Col 8
---- -------- -------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
A    XXX      AAA      5           20190601   PI0104163  20200303   PI0113027  20190531
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIRST_VALUE` `LAST_VALUE`

```
select [Key], [Col 1], [Col 2], [Col 3], min([Col 4]) c4, c5, max([Col 6]) c6 , c7, min([Col 8]) c8
from
  (select [Key], [Col 1], [Col 2], [Col 3], [Col 4]
   , first_value([Col 5]) over (partition by [Key], [Col 1], [Col 2], [Col 3] order by [Col 4] rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following ) c5
   , [Col 6]
   , last_value([Col 7]) over (partition by [Key], [Col 1], [Col 2], [Col 3] order by [Col 6] rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following ) c7
   , [Col 8]
from tbl) t
group by [Key], [Col 1], [Col 2], [Col 3], c5, c7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with window functions like `MIN()` and `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
select distinct
  [Key], Col1, Col2, Col3,
  min(Col4) over (partition by [Key]) Col4,
  first_value(Col5) over (partition by [Key] order by Col4) Col5,
  max(Col6) over (partition by [Key]) Col6,
  first_value(Col7) over (partition by [Key] order by Col6 desc) Col7,
  Col8
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2fd23fa3e3092615d1209803203e9bf7).
Results:

```
> Key | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4     | Col5      | Col6     | Col7      | Col8    
> :-- | :--- | :--- | ---: | :------- | :-------- | :------- | :-------- | :-------
> A   | XXX  | AAA  |    5 | 20190601 | PI0104163 | 20200303 | PI0113027 | 20190531
```